# How can I record video with lossless audio?

Tags: video-recording, audio-recording

The stock video recording app has some preset lossy compression audio setting and I can't find an option to adjust it. I don't like that "tin foil" sound, due to the compression.

Is there a way to have lossless audio when recording video?

(My phone is a two year old LG-P690)